# Pm2 vs Forever for websocket Loadbalancing

Tags: node.js, websocket, load-balancing, forever, pm2

As an infrastructure / Network engineer, i'm not at my advantage when i have to implement Loadbalancing as software solution. Thats why i'm taking the liberty of asking Stack Overflow community the following question:

For Websocket Load-balancing Which package should i use ? PM2 or Forever ?

I'm in charge of the infrastructure of a WebRTC application (NodeJS), The signaling goes as the following scheme :

`caller -> {:80/443} Web/app -> {:wss} API -> {:wss} STUN/TURN`

`callee {:80/443} <- web/app {:wss} <- API {:wss} <- STUN/TURN`

I want to implement some WS Loadbalancing Without setting up a new server. 
Just duplicating the API repo who will run under a new virtual host on the same machine. For finally Loadbalacing the original API and the duplicated one.

The goal is : when a new version of the API is deployed, the API have to be to be stopped for few seconds, crashing the communication of our customers, and i want to avoid that.

Thanks for reading.

Comment: nginx reverse proxy?  Standup api.vNext, add to pool, remove old, stop?  what keeps it up is sort of orthogonal

Comment: The former engineer in charge set up an apache  server, with mod_reverseproxy, mod_proxy_wstunnel, and tons of rewrite rules. Seem i have to deal with apache for this one.

Comment: There's a mod_proxy_balancer in Apache that can be used for load balancing.